# Dynamic and static profile parameters

Tags: sap-basis

How can you determine whether the parameter is dynamic or not?

Answer (score 1):

Look the parameter in transaction RZ11. If it is dynamic you will have a change button.

Answer (score 1):

Checking RZ11. dynamic flag is checked if its a dynamic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think you may check if parameter exists in TPFET table, as I understand only static parameters exists in this table. But may be I mistaken